# how i can integrate octave(matlab clone) with qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, octave

this is my first question . sorry if you find anything stupid.

how i can call octave functions from qt-creator.octave is a matlab clone. i have searched a lot for 1 week but i got more and more confused what should i do. what i have searched is that we can use Qprocess, Qmake and by adding octave libraries. but i cannot understand which method i should adopt .
i have tried to work on this [How to use Octave libraries with C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516356/how-to-use-octave-libraries-with-c) but i cannot understand how to do `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/full/path/to/usr/lib/octave-3.2.4` , do i have to type in terminal or in the .pro of Qt-creator.
 if some one have worked on it. please guide me what should i do.i have spent too much time on it but i not able to find the solution.  please help me.  . thanks!

i have created the gui but now i want to link some octave functions with it. if i press the plot button , using octave built-in function a plot should be displayed

here are codes for the gui i have created

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.show();

return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{

}
```

**gui.pro**

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2014-07-16T17:44:01
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

TARGET = gui
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

i dont have enough reputation to upload the picture of gui

Comment: qt is a C++ library which offers primarily GUI functionality such as `QWidget`, but also things like `QString`. However, it doesn't change basic C++ behavior. If you had made a small non-Qt testprogram to interface with Octave, you could take that code and use it in your Qt project.

Comment: @MSalters i want to create a gui using Qtin which if press the plot button a plot should be displayed using the octave built-in functions. i have to use octave function in my qt c++ code.

Answer (score 0):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is a predefined environment variable which sets the path which the linker should look in to while linking dynamic libraries/shared libraries.

One can use `export variable=value` to set the value of the environment variable named `variable` to some custom value `value`. If the variable does not exist, it will be created.

You can place it at the terminal or in a bash script used to launch your compiled application:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/full/path/to/usr/lib/octave-3.2.4
/usr/bin/myapp
```

Do not forget to check where are the libraries of your installation of Octave. For example, in my Gentoo the Octave libraries are at `/usr/lib/octave/3.6.4`. This is not only important for setting up your execution environment for your application, but to allow the correct linkage of your application, which means you must also adjust accordingly your include path, and libs path (this time inside your `.pro` file).

Despite this, the to the question you pointed is pretty much everything you need to use Octave libraries and run your application: you must only adjust your paths.

Comment: i have solved the problem of libraried. i have pasted the bin folder of octave in path variables. i have posted the codes and i have created the gui . but can please tell me hoe to link it to octave. if i press the plot button of gui . a graph should be displayed using the built-in functionless of octave. thanks

Comment: The compiler is giving you an error? If it is not giving you an error, then your program is being correctly linked with Octave. What error do you get? If it is simply "not plotting", without an actual error message, then your must post more of your code and check again the Octave documentation, since you might be missing something. Also, afaik Octave do not come with out of the box support for plotting (this part is handled by GNUPlot).